# C# - Best way to set Value of Dictionary'Key in Dictionary?

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary` as below:

```
var mapStudent = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<List<Student>, Boolean>>;
```

Now I want to set **`Boolean = true`**, I wrote below:

```
...
var key_value = mapStudent.Where(st => st.Key == classID).First();
var listStudent_EditFlag = key_value.Value;
foreach (KeyValuePair<List<Student>, Boolean> pair in listStudent_EditFlag)
{
    listStudent_EditFlag[pair.Key] = true;
    break;
}
...
```

Doing so is the better practice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: To be honest, this is a disgusting construction ;-) I'd rather create classes  with all needed properties and methods.

Comment: Why would you use `mapStudent.Where(st => st.Key == clasID).First().Value` instead of `mapStudent[classID]`?

Comment: Thank you! I understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry man you ain't going far with your code if you try to deal with such a structure. Since you are talking about best practices, I suggest you to rethink your structure to avoid endless headaches.

If you need to map a list of students to a single property, then maybe you actually need an abstraction over that list of students... i bet we are talking about a class (a school class). This way if you have to deal with a new property of the class tomorrow, you don't have to rewrite all of your code, but just add a property to the SchoolClass class. And **to initilize all of your booleans to true you just need to set true as the default value for your property inside the constructor** of SchoolClass.

Thinking the same way you probably need to abstract a list of ShoolClass mapped to a string to something like a School.

This way the code simplifies and it easier to leverage the power of Linq to perform complex operation and other technologies and of course present the data.

Comment: Thank you! I understood. I would rethink.